# Convert a base class to a derived class

Tags: c#, asp.net, inheritance, type-conversion

I am wondering why this populates the derived class appropriately:

```
BaseClass bc = MethodThatReturnsBaseClassObject();
DerivedClass dc = bc as DerivedClass;
```

But this creates a null derived class object:

```
DerivedClass dc = MethodThatReturnsBaseClassObject() as DerivedClass;
```

Comment: The first one will leave `dc` as a null reference (not an object; just a reference) as well. Try to show a short but complete program demonstrating the problem, and I think you'll find the two are consistent.

Comment: you would have to do something to convert the class.  E.g., override the = operator or create a constructor that takes the base object as a parameter and transforms it into the derived object.

Comment: Thank you for all the information. It is the end of the day, and I guess my brain wasn't working. I see now they are the same. The accepted answer is ultimately what I am trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This happens because `BaseClass` is not an instance of `DerivedClass` (but `DerivedClass` is an instance of `BaseClass`), so you cannot cast an instance of the base class as an instance of the derived class (well, you can, but it will be null as you have found).

You can do what (I think) you are trying to achieve by adding a constructor to the derived class that takes in the base class as a parameter:

```
public DerivedClass(BaseClass baseClass) {
    // Populate common properties, call other derived class constructor, or call base constructor
}
```

Then:

```
 DerivedClass dc = new DerivedClass(MethodThatReturnsBaseClassObject());
```

Answer (score 1):

It is hard to tell without seeing what is coming out of `MethodThatReturnsBaseClassObject();`.

There is absolutely no difference between your statements (if `MethodThatReturnsBaseClassObject();` always returns `DerivedClass` object) other than temporary assignment to `BaseClass` in first case.

If `MethodThatReturnsBaseClassObject()` returns  instance of `BaseClass` dc will always be null. `BaseClass` will hold a reference in this case.

If `MethodThatReturnsBaseClassObject()` returns  instance of `DerivedClass` dc will have reference (and will not be null).